# find a sequence of functions that fullfill the condition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, sequence-of-function

Find a sequence of functionf $f_n$ on [0,1] that

- $0\le f_n(x)\le1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$
- every function $f_n$ is continious
- the function $x\rightarrow sup_{n\in\Bbb N}f_n(x)$ is not continous

I had something in mind: $$f_n(x)=\frac{n}{nx+1}$$
but this wouldn't fullfill the 3rd condition

Could use some hint

Comment: $f_n(x)=nx$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x)=1$ on $(1/n,1]$.

Comment: @Surb that works too!

Comment: Try $f_n(x)=1-x^n$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That works too! Intuitively, you want functions where the gradient increases without bound at at least one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

$$f_n(x) := \sqrt[n]{x}$$

Then clearly $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $n$ and all $x \in [0, 1]$.

And all of these functions are continuous on $[0, 1]$.

And notice $\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big\{ \sqrt[n]{0} \big\}=0$, but for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big\{ \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon} \big\} = 1$.**

So for any $x\in (0,1]$, we have $\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big\{ \sqrt[n]{x} \big\}=1$, but when $x=0$ then this function outputs $0$. Therefore, it is not continuous on $[0, 1]$.

**I have left the proof that this limit equals 1 as an exercise for you!